# Batch extracting specific file types from master directory with many subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I have a quantity of folders with archive files,
Parent folder with subfolder eg

Graphics:

- graphics 01012021/file31241.7z
- graphics 01022021/file4231.7z
- odds and ends 01032022/filejohnny.7z

etc
each folder contains an archive - various names numbers.
each archives contains various files, pdf's txt files invoices and image files.
Generally the images are .jpg named various names.

What I would like to do is batch attack the parent folder to extract an image file/s from the each archive from each sub directory and leave the image in the subdirectory with the archive where it came from. If the archive has multiple images that's fine, I am not targeting a single particular image.

hopefully ending up with something like

Graphics:

- graphics 01012021/
  file31241.7z
  yellowstone.jpg
  flintstone.jpg
- graphics 01022021/
  file4231.7z
  martha.jpg
- odds and ends 01032022/
  filejohnny.7z
  artemis.jpg
  French toast.png

I would rather avoid if possible extracting all the files separating the images then having to re archive.

What I tried to discover originally was to batch extract the image files to the directory it belongs to, have the image file renamed to its directory name. I didn't get close with a solution, so I think if possible just extracting the image would be fine and I can use a renaming app to do the other I've found bulk rename utility to be just fine once I got my head around it.
You wouldn't think that over the years you would collect so many archives, like small drops they ended up become an ocean full.

I have tried researching stack and seen a lot of examples of how eg 7zip works but I just cant get my head quite around it.

I am due to retire they tell me 65 is the time for the chicken coop, I've been a pencil pusher and mouse skater most of my life in the gfx industry. I used to know what was in each archive but memory is a little how to say... rusty nowadays, I know all my archives have images in them. My life would be a lot easier in the sunset of it to look at the pictures and not have to rack my brains trying to remember what was in the archive itself.

Cheers and ty in advance from the colonies downunder.

Grumpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "extensions=bat txt"
SET "archives=7z zip"

CALL :prefix sdexts *. %extensions%
CALL :prefix sdarchives *. %archives%
CALL :prefix dexts . %extensions%
CALL :prefix darchives . %archives%

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /s /a-d %sdexts% %sdarchives%') DO (
 SET "unreported=%%b"
 FOR %%o IN (%darchives%) DO IF /i "%%~xb"=="%%o" CALL :procarch%%o&SET "unreported="
 IF DEFINED unreported ECHO %%~dpb ^| %%~nxb
)
)>"%outfile%"

popd

GOTO :EOF

:: return %1 with each other argument preceded by '%2'

:prefix 
SET "$1=%1="
shift
SET "$2=%~1"
:sdl
SHIFT
IF "%1"=="" SET "%$1%"&GOTO :eof
SET "$1=%$1% %$2%%1"
GOTO sdl

:: Process .7z or .zip archives

:procarch.7z
:procarch.zip
SET "skipme=Y"
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('7z L "%unreported%"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=3delims= " %%o IN ("%%e") DO (
 IF "%%o"=="------------" (
  IF DEFINED skipme (SET "skipme=") ELSE (SET "skipme=Y")
 ) ELSE IF NOT DEFINED skipme ECHO "%%o"|FIND "D" >NUL &IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET "filename=%%e"
  FOR /f "delims=" %%y IN ("!filename:~53!") DO (
   FOR %%c IN (%dexts%) DO IF /i "%%c"=="%%~xy" ECHO %unreported% ^| %%y
  )
  )
 )
)

GOTO :eof
```

I've a similar requirement, so I spent a bit of time on this...

The first part simply sets the directories to be used.

I used `bat` and `txt` as extensions required for testing. Change as desired - just a space-separated list.

Similarly, I chose to examine `.zip` and `.7z` archives. Since `7zip` can deal with both, the same subroutine can be used to process both. Other archive types may need different processing.

The code uses `dir` to locate the files of interest, and `dir` can take a series of arguments, so the routine `:prefix` converts the list provided as %3+ to a list in variable %1, each term prefixed by the string at %2.

So - `sdexts` will become `*.bat *.txt` and `dexts` `.bat .txt` for instance.

Next, switch to the source dir to begin the `dir` to list the required files. For each name returned in `%%b` (`delims=` applies the full name, `/b` basic list (names only), `/s` processes subdirectories, `/a-d` suppresses directorynames) - the flag `unreported` is set to the filename found then the extension of the filename found is compared to the `darchives` list. If a match is found, execute the `procarch%%o` routine is executed and the `unreported` flag set to *empty*. Then, if `unreported` has not been cleared, it's not an archive file, so report it.

`procarch%%o` will be resolved either `procarch.7z` or `procarch.zip` and a routine (actually the same routine) is provided.

The `:prefix` routine sets `$1` to `%1=`, so for example, `sdexts=`. Then it shifts the parameter list and sets `$2` to the prefix to be placed before each term.

Then shift again. If `%1` is not empty, append a space and the prefix in `$2` and `%1` to `$1` and repeat.

When `%1` becomes empty, execute the command `set "%$1%" and finish, so as` $1`would then contain the string`sdexts= *.bat *.txt`,` sdexts` would be set to the list required.

The routine `:procarch.7z` or `procarch.zip` (the first simply `falls through` to the second, so the same processing is executed) sets the flag `skipme` to non-empty as we need to skip `7z`'s header data.

`%%e` acquires each line of the `7z L` report in turn. `%%o` is assigned the third token of the `7z` report line. This will be junk up to the line with a series of dashes, then the attribute report for the archived items, then another series of dashes, then junk.

So - if `%%o` is a string of dashes, simply switch `skipme` to empty/not empty.

If `%%o` is not dashes, and `skipme` is not defined then we are between the two lines of dashes (ie. on an archived item line) so we see whether `%%o` contains `D` (which would indicate that this is a directory name, which we do not want to report). If it does not, `errorlevel` will be set non-zero by the `find` (output of the `find` is sent to `nul`=the æther) `filename` set to the full report line. We're not interested in the first 54 characters, but the remainder contains the archived filename, so see whether the extension of the filename found is one of interest (in `dexts`) and if it is, report it.

The `(` on the line preceding the `for ... %%b` matches the `)>"%outfile%"` and sends all output that would otherwise go to the console to the file named.

And the `^|` on the `echo` lines output a literal `|` character as `|` is a special character for `cmd` and needs to be `escaped` by `^` to be interpreted as a literal.

Comment: Oh my good Lord! Like I said I was more a pencil pusher and mouse skater. I thank you so much for the code and excellent explanation on how and why it works. I could have sat here for a month of Sunday's and I couldn't possibly even dream of a solution like that.
Thank you ever so much Mr Magoo (one of my childhood favourite cartoon characters lol)
I hope I have enough intelligence now to make it work.

Thank you again for an enormous amount of effort you have put in to this and for sharing your solution.

Cheers

Comment: Hey G'day,so I get now a .txt file which lists the .jpgs contained in the archives. How do you now convert your script above to actually extract the files in the same manner same formatting. The text file is perfect it lists the jpgs has the appropriate directories etc. I need to have the .jpgs extracted to their relative directory/s.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question the task is simple involving `For` loops with recursion, however to be robust the solution will be complex without knowing how those specific long term possibly mixed, 7zip files are subdivided, thus if a 7zip has itself two sub folders with identical named files you will hit error conditions. I have allowed for that using -aou to auto rename if necessary. however I have not added the folder name to each file as that's an extra step.

```
@echo off & Title Extract Images from 7z files
set "extractor=C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
set "archives=*.7z"
set "filetypes=*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.tif *.tiff"
set "startDir=C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop"

FOR /R "%startdir%" %%I IN (%archives%) DO ( "%extractor%" e "%%I" -o"%%~dpI" %filetypes% -aou)
```

You can add extra archive types such as .rar or .zip in the same way I have allowed for different image file types. HOWEVER do test for such variations first otherwise a second run will invoke that autonaming of existing duplicates. ***You can of course change that -aou to -aos to avoid overwite or remove it as desired***.

An alternative approach on windows is that, standard windows.zip files can be navigated and thus kept as compressed folders where a click on each file will open in the default application. Thus only need extraction to the folder when you wish to use a non default app.

[image]

The secondary advantage more directly related to your need is that some viewers can read just the images and ignore any other contents (even if they can read text or html) and one I support that reads images in zips is SumatraPDF and although not listed it can open .7Z files to show in the same way

[image]

Hence my answer to the posed question is I suggest converting 7zip to standard zip rather than expand them, or use SumatraPDF as default/alternative 7z viewer !!.

Comment: Hey G'day,

Thank you for taking the time to help me out here. All the files are unique in naming convention unless I have made an error over the years and duplicated a file name by mistake. All of my image files have been tagged with a unique client number with date and numbering system so no two files should be the same.
I use a win app called Total Commander which is great for looking into an archive extracting single files and putting them where I want but over 20 years of files its a very slow process extracting files from archives one by one.

Comment: I'll have a look at sumatrapdf I've not seen or heard of that before. TY again for the time and courtesy of a reply.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts I did have a look at Sumatra, that would have been a handy program to use for sure many years ago, I could have incorporated it into my workflow. Unfortunately of little use as I really do need to extract the files and place them in their own directory's. I had a better look at totalcommander as well it does have a function under File, where you can unpack a specific file whatever that file might be. Fantastic for extracting particular files per directory. Unfortunately no batch operation. I wish I'd discovered that many years ago. Slister will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my issue, no coding just using an app I've been using for years. Total Commander.

Solution was simple in the end.

I open up Total Commander, do a search for the archive files I want Alt F7 it will list in the right hand frame all my archives .7z .zip whatever you have.

Then you select "feed to list box" found in the bottom right hand corner. Do a Ctrl A then Alt F9 which gives you some options.

You clear unpack specific files from archive to "make sure its blank" then files to unpack tell it what your looking for in my case .jpg (it can be any specific file).

Untick unpack path names if stored with files
tick or untick overwrite existing files
untick unpack each archive to a separate subdir (name of the archive)
Hit ok.

It will then search and find the file/s you are looking for and unpack them in the directory/subdirectory/etc they are found in.

Job done... No coding just using TC.. marvellous app

Comment: XTree was my goto for many years, my sentiments exactly Symantec lost the plot totally.